# Predictions after modeling: output array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

After fitting a decision tree I want to do some predictions.

- **How can I make this output predicted array more readable ?**
  As you can see, the output corresponds to the features' input values but how can I show the corresponding names above the values? For example the first value is `0.28945` corresponding to a column named `time_ms` but since i have multiple columns I can't distinguish all of them. How can I display the names above the input values?
- These input values return a classification into `[1]` corresponding to the value "yes". **How can I replace it to display `yes` instead of `1`**
- Finally, is it useful (or the best way) to do predictions like this when there are multiple features and not just two just like in the Iris database (petal length, width) ?

```
clf_dt_grid = grid_search_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_grid = grid_search_cv.predict(X_test)

#Predictions on training set
yhat= clf_dt_grid.predict(X_train)
acc = accuracy_score(y_train,yhat)
print(f'Train predictions accuracy : {acc}%')

#New input for predictions 
new_input = [[0.28945,6593,0,178,2,154.5,True,6593.0,4.0,0,1,2.0,0.00,862.0,0.21,524103.0,2]]
new_output = clf_dt_grid.predict(new_input)
print(new_input,new_output)

>>> [[0.28945, 6593, 0, 178, 2, 154.5, True, 6593.0, 4.0, 0, 1, 2.0, 0.0, 862.0, 0.21, 524103.0, 2]] [1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your train/test data into a pandas dataframe and then everything would be more readable.

For example, list out the column names and then use the dataframe constructor like this:

```py
col_names = ['time_ms', 'col2', 'col3',..., 'colN']
train_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names, data=X_train)
test_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names, data=X_test)
```

Then for your new predictions, you can structure it the same way in a data frame (e.g. call it `new_input`, then call predict:

```py
new_output = clf_dt_grid.predict(new_input.iloc[0].values) # get the first row of values only

print(new_input.iloc[0], new_output)
```